# Calculate minimums in Pandas without `zero`-values?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a following data and need on first step to find `min` values among rows without `0.00`

```
HOME_48  HOME_24  HOME_12  HOME_03  HOME_01  HOME_00   HOME  
   0.00     1.54     2.02     1.84     1.84     1.84   1.84  
   0.00     1.47     1.76     1.89     2.56     2.56   2.56  
   0.00     2.02     2.50     2.56     1.89     1.92   1.92
```

Later I need calculate delta-diff between `min` and `max`, but if I use below code, the end-results are not acceptable

```
df['HOME_MIN'] = df.loc[:, COL_HOME].min(axis=1)
```

I don't want use following tricks:

```
df = df.replace(0, np.NaN)
```

Beacuse, sometimes the extreme values can be equal as `0.01`, `0.02` - these ones are not correct values also.

How can I add condition to skip `0.00`| `0.01` values?

NOTE: correct  filter is

```
df[df[COL_HOME].min(axis=1) > 0.03].loc[:, COL_HOME].min(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use a boolean filter to exclude whatever you don't want, like this.

```
In [46]: df[df > .01].min(axis=1)
Out[46]: 
0    1.54
1    1.47
2    1.89
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I need to find `min` values among specific cols as `df.loc[:, COL_HOME].min(axis=1)`. How I can modify your example?

Comment: You can just select after filtering, e.g. `df[df > .01].loc[:, COL_HOME].min(axis=1)`

Comment: Added as you mentioned, `df['HOME_MIN'] = df[df > 0.03].loc[:, COL_HOME].min(axis=1)` and struggling with output http://screencast.com/t/fD5rcmb7 .